# Datetime to nullable datetime converter automapper

Tags: c#, entity-framework, datetime, mapping, automapper

I use AutoMapper and I have a situation where my Model (use EntityFramework) require DateTime properties but my POCOs use nullable datetimes.

When `ItemModel.OtherDate.Year==1900` the `ItemPOCO.MyDate` should be `null`.

Any way to convert DateTime to Nullable DateTime with different property names?

I tried this, but it does not work: `Property 'Int32 Year' is not defined for type 'System.Nullable'1[System.DateTime]'`

```
// Class Model (EntityFramework)
public class ItemModel{
  public DateTime OtherDate { get; set; }
}

// POCO
public class ItemPOCO{
  public DateTime? MyDate { get; set; }
}

// AutoMapper Profile
public class MappingProfile : Profile
{
  public MappingProfile()
  {
    CreateMap<ItemModel, ItemPOCO>()
      .ForMember(poco => poco.MyDate, 
                 opt => opt.MapFrom(m => m.OtherDate.Year == 1900 ? null : new DateTime?(m.OtherDate)));
  }
}
```

[image: Error message]

Comment: If I copy your code, it works fine..

Comment: @MarkC. you are right !
The problem ocurred in AutoMapper 5.0.2. I updated to version 5.1.1 and it's fine :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem ocurred in AutoMapper 5.0.2. I updated to version 5.1.1 and it's fine :)